# Spring 4 PropertyPlaceholder with Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, properties-file

Okay, I know this question has been asked several times over and I've tried every solution from their suggested answers but have yet to find one that works so I'm hoping someone on here can point me in the right direction.

I am trying to use Spring 4 with a Java-centric configuration but am having issues loading properties from a properties file.  My latest approach is following almost verbatim Spring's documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) but even that isn't working.

Here is my properties-config.xml file (located within a /config directory on my classpath):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

</beans>
```

Here is my web app initializer class (a snippet, anyways):

```
public class TestWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext container)
   {
      // Instantiate a new web application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = 
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

      // Load the configurations
      appContext.scan("com.acme.config");
      appContext.refresh();

      // Add the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

      // Add the various listeners
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
      container.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
   }
}
```

And then finally a small sample configuration class which utilizes the properties file:

```
package com.acme.config;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:config/properties-config.xml")
public class HibernateConfiguration
{
   @Value("${jdbc.url}")
   private String jdbcUrl;

   @Value("${jdbc.username}")
   private String jdbcUsername;

   @Value("${jdbc.password")
   private String jdbcPassword;

   @Bean(name = "dataSource")
   public ComboPooledDataSource getDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException
   {
      // Define a variable to hold the result
      ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

      System.out.println("URL: " + jdbcUrl);
      System.out.println("Username: " + jdbcUsername);
      System.out.println("Password: " + jdbcPassword);

      // Set the properties for the data source
      ds.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
      ds.setUser(jdbcUsername);
      ds.setPassword(jdbcPassword);

      // Return the result
      return ds;
   }
}
```

And last but not least, the properties file:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test
jdbc.username=myusername
jdbc.password=mypassword
```

The System.out.println statements all return "null" for each of the values which prevents my data source from getting setup.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to add stuff to the `properties-config.xml`? If not, you can just add a `@PropertySources` to the `@Configuration` class.

Comment: BTW, you have type. Should be `  @Value("${jdbc.password}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *finally* found the issue.  Actually, there were two.  First, the order of the Bean definitions appeared to have mattered.  Once I reordered them into a more appropriate order (ie, beanA is created first, beanB references beanA, beanC references beanA and beanB) it seemed to make a difference.

The main issue, however, was that there was a Bean definition for a `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` within the `HibernateConfiguration` class.  This definition is why the `Environment` variable was null and no properties were being resolved.

Thanks to @Artem Bilan for all the help!

Comment: `BeanPostProcessor`s have to be configured as `static` `@Bean` and right, they shouldn't have any dependencies from other beans. Mark them with `static` allow to configure `BPP` first, and only after that all other stuff: autowiring, property-placeholder etc. for other beans

Comment: I can't upvote this enough.  This was exactly my issue.  Yes when using hibernate, I also use the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, but NONE of the other solutions out there mention that this bean also has to be static.  It makes sense, but wasn't obvious until now.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: The "ordering" thing had me stuck banging my head for hours.  Really disappointed this wasn't easier to configure.  Got it working finally, after reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The real issue here that annotation configuration is loaded before any imported XML and you really have to move the property-placeholder configuration to the `@Configuration`:

```
@Configuration    
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Pay attention, please, for the `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean definition. Without it you can get access to you properties from file only using autowired `Environment`.

From here that property-placeholder configuration will be available for imported xml too.

For more info see `PropertySource` JavaDocs

Comment: So this is one of the most common solutions offered by many of the other threads and it still does not work for me.  I changed the 
    '@ImportResource' 
annotation to 
    '@PropertySource' 
and pointed it to "classpath:db.properties" and added the static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer method but no luck.

Am I reading the Spring documentation wrong then?  I thought I was following it line per line?

Comment: Is it `classpath:db.properties` really correct path? Do you really use correct keys from that file?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct path and yes, the keys, as you can see, are correct - and I have fixed the typo, thanks!  When I had a purely XML configuration, this is the section that provided the path which did work correctly:

`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
   <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties" />
</bean>`

Comment: OK. I suggest you to debug you app: to take a look what does `Environmet` have; try to load your file using `PropertiesFactoryBean`. BTW, have you marked `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` with `@Bean` ?

Comment: Yeah, I have it marked exactly as you have it above.

Comment: So I now added the '@Environment' variable via the '@Autowired' annotation to my HibernateConfiguration class and when I check it, it is null.  So I am guessing that something is setup incorrectly but I don't know what.

Comment: Well, I suggest you to share somewhere your project. At least the result WAR

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe I can do that.  I am creating a very simple Spring web app to see if I can reproduce the issue with nothing else in the way.  My main webapp is pretty large so I'm hoping that by reducing the clutter, the problem will be more obvious.

Comment: So creating a very simple Spring application using the '@PropertySources' and '@Autowired' Environment variable seems to work fine so something is definitely funky with my main webapp.  Now I just need to figure out what it is...

Comment: You don't need the static `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Only adding the `@PropertySource` is enough to get the `@Value` annotations processed. You only need the method if you don't use an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` these 2 automatically register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, can you show, please, where they do it? I just follow with `@PropertySource` JavaDocs

Comment: I was wrong, must have been spoiled by Spring Boot :). One indeed needs the static bean definition, I was under the impression that with Spring 4 and the revamped java-config it wasn't needed anymore.